# How to init KeyValueStore without conversion in KafkaStreams?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In the 27th line of code: [github](https://github.com/bbejeck/kafka-streams-in-action/blob/master/src/main/java/bbejeck/chapter_4/transformer/PurchaseRewardTransformer.java)

we can find how the author of the book `Kafka Streams in Action` initialize KeyValueStore. He uses dirty conversion `(KeyValueStore)`.

```
public class PurchaseRewardTransformer implements ValueTransformer<Purchase, RewardAccumulator> {

    private KeyValueStore<String, Integer> stateStore;
    private final String storeName;
    private ProcessorContext context;

    public PurchaseRewardTransformer(String storeName) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(storeName,"Store Name can't be null");
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        stateStore = (KeyValueStore) this.context.getStateStore(storeName);
    }

// ...
```

How to do it in more polite way?

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessorContext.getStateStore` doesn't return a defined type of store, it returns an interface, and so it must be cast if you need to use specific methods of that implementation